# What is the format of an affidavit of declaration for signing in the vernacular language of a deceased person?

Tags: legal-writing

A person has signed in her vernacular language in some official documents and she has passed away. In her identity document, her name is written in English. As a nominee, her son is asked to provide an affidavit which will declare that the person who has signed in vernacular language and the person whose identity proof is going to be provided are the same.

What could be written in the affidavit for such case?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the son would need to attest to the fact that the person who signed one document as அகமகிழ்தினி is the same person identified on another document as "Akamakiltini" are the same person. That would be so even if the signed document had மலர்மதி for a signature, though in that case the affidavit may need to explain the discrepancy. If the son is familiar with his mother's writing and can swear that the signature of document A that looks like "அகமகிழ்தினி" is indeed how his mother wrote her name, and that her name is indeed (in Latin characters) Akamakiltini or some variant spelling, he would state that basis. Or, he might attest that "my mother often wrote மலர்மதி when she signed her name".

Comment: Just so. These affidavits are called "one and the same" affidavits and also used when someone dies and they have a common first and last name (e.g. "Jesus Gomez", or "Henry Kim") to confirm that the person on a death certificate and the person in a legal document are the same person.